# Dataset and Face Detector for Facial Landmarks of Profile Face

Tags: dataset, computer-vision

I built a facial landmark predictor for frontal faces (similar to 68 landmarks of dlib). Now, I would like to continue to profile faces. Firstly, what I need is:
1 - A robust detector for profile face.
2 - Profile faces dataset and corresponding landmarks (key-points) annotations.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The only freely available annotated profile dataset that I know  of is the [CPFW](http://www.cfpw.io/).
If you work with an academic institution you could try to obtain [iBug](https://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/resources/2nd-facial-landmark-tracking-competition-menpo-ben/) or [AFLW](https://www.tugraz.at/institute/icg/research/team-bischof/lrs/downloads/aflw) datasets.

To detect profile faces you could use the deep learning face detector available in dlib 19.4. Another option would be using openCV HaarCascade detector loaded with profile model.

Comment: Where can I find the DL face detector in dlib?

Comment: it says on the iBug site that training images were obtained from the AFLW image set and FDDB I believe so would getting both be redundant?

Answer (score 0):

I am using dlib shape detector to train on profile face. However, I do not know of a profile face dataset and annotations that already exist. I am creating a small dataset of my own using the imglab tool from dlib. You can check it out here [dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use MTCNN which is the face detection method based on CNN. This is really robust to the profile face.

https://github.com/kpzhang93/MTCNN_face_detection_alignment

Comment: I noticed that sometimes you may need to flip and rotate images fed to MTCNN to detect all faces.  Maybe even shrink or enlarge depending on the head size in image as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative proposal.  Run head detection rather than face detection.  But you would still have to create a dataset for profile faces as I cannot find one yet.

For face detection, I am currently running DFSD by Tencent on the video on which I want to detect profile faces.  It seems more robust than MTCNN on frontal faces oriented sideways (person lying down).

[Tencent DFSD](https://github.com/TencentYoutuResearch/FaceDetection-DSFD)

Head detection has a few Github repos but this one looks really good with models, Arxiv paper and examples:

[head detection](https://github.com/nyck33/cnn_head_detection)

I'll add a profile face dataset here if I find one. Actually just realized one of the answers above mentions a few such iBug and AFLW, etc.